# Salt using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, salt

I'm working on a basic PHP login for the very first time using a udemy online course.

I'm really struggling already as my code, which is in the tutorial, gives an error when I open the page!

All I have, saved in a file called salt.php is:

```
<?php

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024);
var_dump($salt);

?>
```

Seems pretty basic, and I'm running this with WAMP. But I just get an error message instead of outputting the random characters.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() in C:\wamp\www\login-register\salt.php on line 3
```

Comment: You PHP install is probably missing the OpenSSL module.

Comment: [how to check your modules](http://php.net/extension_loaded)

Comment: Please also have a look at the function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it was especially designed to handle the difficult parts like generating a safe salt. If you are interested in more indepth information, you may have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).